# psql:pr_staging.sql:7624: ERROR: relation "res_company" already exists

Tags: postgresql, odoo, backup, restore

Backup command: pg_dump -U username backupdbname -f backupfilename.sql
Restore Command:  psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 -f backupfilename.sql -d newdbname;

Actually Tried this command. Backup is working. But while restoring it will throw error psql:pr_staging.sql:7624: ERROR:  relation "res_company" already exists. Because for restore, we need one newdb. So that i am creating newdb from browser manually. Thats why i facing the error.

I am creating a new db using terminal command. But it not showing in browser localhost:8069/web/database/selector.

How to restore the backup db?

Answer (score 0):

If you create a db by using Odoo's db manager (interface) there already will be basic tables (the module base will be installed automatically).

There are some ways to restore the db. For example (template0 is a default template db from postgres):

```
createdb -T template0 newdbname
cat backupfilename | psql newdbname
```

You shouldn't have a Odoo server running while doing this.

You could also use Odoo's database interface to backup and restore/duplicate databases.